# Redis Replication and Cluster difference

Tags: java, node.js, spring, caching, redis

Currently my Spring boot application has one redis server.

Now that I want to make the redis server **high available**, which approach should I follow?

For example I would have master, slaves and sentinel set up where if my master goes down automatically new master got elect and application works normal. **Does that approch is called replication with automatic failover?**

On the other hand **how does cluster differ from above mentioned (replication) set up**. Does it also has the support of sentinel servers for automatic failover?

And in terms of data, I read, cluster split data among multiple nodes instead relication has the exact copy of data of master in all slaves. In that case **splitting data in multiple nodes of a cluster, would lead to stale data situation if some nodes go down**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have more data than RAM on a machine, use redis cluster to shard the data across machines. Redis cluster supports master-slave replication and failover itself and doesn't need sentinel. If you have failures with a node, it will keep working until the majority of master nodes fail.

I you have less data than RAM on a machine, setup a master/slave replication with sentinel in front to handle the failover.

https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial

Comment: But then in a redis cluster some master nodes could not have some data right? In that case if a request comes to fetch a data, does it search the data in all masters? If not doesnt it lead to stale data situation?

Comment: When a client connects to a cluster node and asks for data, the node will either respond with the data if it has it, or tell the client which other node contains the data. There shouldn't be stale data unless something goes wrong, see https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial#redis-cluster-consistency-guarantees

Comment: In fact, the client has to know the Cluster node it hits. All Java clients do that so the client selects the node it talks to to read or write a particular key.

Comment: @ChrisTanner In a redis replication, how can we configure the reads to be happen only in slaves? Is it the default behavior where writes happen in master and reads happen in slaves?

Comment: @Harshana your application code needs to request either a master or a slave.